# Adding a new button after an event

Tags: java, awt

Writing a program to increment a counter when a +1 button is pressed, then when the counter reaches a certain number, remove the +1 button and replace it with a +2 button and so on. I create both buttons at first but just set btnCount1 to setVisible(false). When the certain number passes, I make btnCount invisible and btnCount1 visible and increment by two from there. When it reaches 10 clicks, the btnCount disappears, but btnCount1 does not appear.

I have tried making an if(arg0.equals(btnCount1)), and incrementing by two from there. I tried putting the add(btnCount1) inside the else if statement to create it after the elseif condition is true.

```
public class AWTCounter extends Frame implements ActionListener
private Label lblCount;
private TextField tfCount;
private Button btnCount;
private Button btnCount1;
private int count = 0;

public AWTCounter() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());


    lblCount = new Label("Counter");
    add(lblCount);

    tfCount = new TextField(count + "",10);
    tfCount.setEditable(false);
    add(tfCount);

    btnCount = new Button("Add 1");
    btnCount1 = new Button("Add 2");
    add(btnCount);
    add(btnCount1);
    btnCount1.setVisible(false);

    btnCount.addActionListener(this);
    btnCount1.addActionListener(this);


    setTitle("AWT Counter");
    setSize(500,500);

}

public static void main(String[]args) {
    AWTCounter app = new AWTCounter();
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    if(count <= 10) {
        ++count; //Increase the counter value
        tfCount.setText(count + "");
    }else if(count > 10) {
        btnCount.setVisible(false);
        btnCount1.setVisible(true);
        count += 2;
        tfCount.setText(count + "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing.

Answer (score 0):

The better solution here is to just have one button object and a separate variable for the current increment amount. When you hit the required count, increase the increment amount and [change the button's label](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Button.html#setLabel-java.lang.String-) to the new value.

There are also a few other things you could do better here.

- Use `String.valueOf()` instead of `int + ""` for `String` representations of integers if you're not adding words before or after the integer.
- Don't add obvious comments for code. (e.g. *'increment variable x'*, *'set textString to the new value'*)
- Use descriptive names for method parameters and variables.
- Use `Labels` instead of `TextFields` for text that doesn't need to be editable or selectable like counter displays.

I'd personally change the name of `lblCount` to something like `lblTitle` as well, since changing your `tfCount` to a `Label` would logically take up that name and `lblTitle` makes more sense.

Here's a better way to implement `actionPerformed`:

```
private int increment = 1;
private Label lblCount;
...
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ignore) {
    if(count == 10) {
        btnCount.setLabel("Add " + (++increment));
    }

    lblCount.setText(String.valueOf(count += increment));
}
```